# The meaning of "that" in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> "He was given no direction or no influence, other than that of fair chance."

Here, what meaning does *that* have?

Comment: You don't need the second *no* before *influence.*

Answer (score 1):

[That](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that?q=That):

> Referring to a specific thing previously mentioned, known, or understood

So it refers to "direction or influence".

Comment: It's kind of a pronoun. "Which direction or influence? The direction or influence of fair chance".